# Flutter reactive ble or Flutter blue which package is best

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im going to start bluetooth project in flutter, can anyone suggest which package is best for production.

My case is to connect with smartwatches,weightscale,bp devices to get the medical data.

Flutter blue:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue

Flutter reactive ble:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble

Comment: what is your use case? can you explain more please?

Comment: data updated @reza

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which ble package that is best is a personal opinion. But I have spent the last four years on making apps that use ble to talk to iOT devices. I have use three different packages:

- I used [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) in production about 4 years ago. I was not happy with it(I don't remember exactly why). They made breaking changes that included a switch to RxDart so there where no reason to stay with flutter _blue.
- When I started to develop a new app I selected [flutter_ble_lib](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ble_lib). The reason for that was that the main developers come from the consultant company Polidea. But Polidea was bought by an other company and they stopped developing packages. So I had to change ble package to be able to keep my app upgraded.
- I asked google if they had any plans on making a ble package, they said no. But they recommended [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble). So I have been using flutter_reactive_ble since then. It is Philips Hue that develop it for their smart lamps. The reasons why I prefer flutter_reactive_ble:

  - I think its the more stable choice because of its developed by Philips hue. It is as good as it get when it comes to stability.
  - I use the library to tell iOT devises how to connect to internet. It's the probably what this package is made for.

Comment: Hi Henge, you wrote that you used this package to tell the iot device how to connect please can you give me an example of how your code looks like? Cause i was working with flutter blue , but when I moved to this package I can't figure out how can i send Strings as password and wifi name , the dialogue show just a number field ,and when i tried to change the argument type (List<int>) it just asks for more modifications until I guessed that package itself don't allow Strings ,i thought i can solve it just by changing the example files,so please can you clarify me that?

Comment: @KMB90 I used protobuf to comunicate with the iot device. See https://pub.dev/packages/protoc_plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Flutter reactive ble is better since It has lesser reported issues.

**please read this disclaimer by flutter_blue team**

> This library is actively developed alongside production apps, and the
> API will evolve as we continue our way to version 1.0.
>
> Please be fully prepared to deal with breaking changes. This package
> must be tested on a real device.

Flutter reactive ble is a lot more stable and it's not a newly started project. It's been tested and fixed over a long course of time.

Comment: But flutter blue package got more popularity and likes than the reactive ble you can check it in pub page  and also in other pages https://fluttergems.dev/bluetooth-nfc-beacon/. may I know you opinion on this?

Comment: You already got your answer. You explicitly asked for "which package is best for production." ;-)

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: Both packages are good. But the one best for production is the one that took more time to test and fix bugs. The one which has the least bugs are best for production. Please check the reported issues on both the plugins and compare.

Comment: Both libraries are incomplete and you should expect issues. Especially with devices that require bonding.

Comment: Martin, curious your thoughts on FlutterBluePlus. They added bonding support. I saw your great android BLE articles.

Answer (score 2):

Other good option is [flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus). It's a fork of [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) and it's actively maintained.
I started with flutter_blue but last commit was two years ago. Then I decided to switch to flutter_blue_plus

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [FlutterBluePlus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus).

It has improved a ton this past year (600 commits).

- no dependencies (FlutterReactiveBle uses protobuf, melos, and more)
- a *much* simpler code base. Android & iOS are just single files.
- exhaustive error checking
- really useful logs, *with color*
- consistently coded, very reliabile

If you want to be able to easily understand the code, I would recommend FlutterBluePlus. What I dislike most about FlutterReactiveBle is how complex the platform code is. It seems over-engineered, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Neither flutter_blue nor flutter_reactive_ble support a device that has multiple (different) characteristics with the same UUID.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).